# Saving the Popup data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am having a drop down with "Create New" option. If User clicks "Create New" option then Popup window will display with Save button. In that Popup window, User will enter data and after User will save this data on server. To achieve this what approach I should follow. Any Help Please..??

Comment: look into AngularJs along with bootstrap or Jquery popup plugins.

Comment: on **Save button** you can issue a post request using ajax, and persisting these data into db.

Answer (score 1):

use for example from javascript:

```
$(function () {
        $("#btnSave").click(function () {
            var person = { Name: 'MrX', Age: 25 };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/AddUser",
                data: car,
                datatype: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    /*
                    done
                    */
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

and then into your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddUser(string data)
        {
/* deserilize and insert */
```

or if you are using web forms you need to decorate your method like:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void AddUser(string data)
{
/* deserialize, add */
```

*Note: out there are so many options you can do this. it depends in what conditions you are or what you like*

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript function to call C# Web Method from Ajax.

```
    <script> 
       function savefile() 
       {

            var person = 'test',
                returnEmail = 'test@test.com';
            var dataValue = { "name": person, "returnAddress": returnEmail };

            var url = "WebForm1.aspx/OnSubmit";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: JSON.stringify(dataValue), 
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(msg) {
                    if (msg.d != null) {
                        alert("We returned: " + msg.d);
                    }
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        };
    </script>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="savefile()" />
```

Web Method to receive Ajax Request and Process it.

```
using System.Web.Services;
[WebMethod]
public static string OnSubmit(string name, string returnAddress)
{
    return "it worked";
    //Code for writing your data to text file.
}
```

Comment: I have created script like this. But it is not working. Can you please tell me whats wrong in that.                                          $(document).ready(function () {
$('#SaveinFile').click(function () {
$.ajax({
url: 'D:\C#.Net\Scramble.Txt',
datatype: "json",
method: 'post',
success: function (data) {
var scrtabledata = $('#modaltable');
scrtabledata.empty();
$(data).each(function () {
scrtabledata.append('<tr><td>' + scrtabledata.comment + '</td><td>' + scrtabledata.DropDownList2 + '</td><td>' + scrtabledata.DropDownList1 + '</td></tr>');

Comment: can you please send me code for this so i can test it  ?

Comment: <script> function savefile() {
var krk;
$('#modaltable tbody tr td:nth-child(1)').each(function () {
krk += $(this).text();
 });   $.ajax({
 url: 'D:\C#.Net\Scramble.txt',
 datatype: "json",
 method: 'post',
 data: scrtabledata,
 success: function () {
 var scrtabledata = $('#modaltable'); //Table ID
 scrtabledata.empty();
 $(data).each(function () {
 scrtabledata.append('<table><tbody><tr><td>' + scrtabledata.comment + '</td><td>' + scrtabledata.DropDownList2 + '</td><td>' + scrtabledata.DropDownList1 + '</td></tr></tbody></table>');
 });
 }
            });
        };
    </script>

Comment: I have rewritten your code and updated my answer please check it. Its working

Comment: No element found error is coming while debugging the code.